# ASP.NET Core Server Side Validation: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

In my entity model I have a required attribute:

```
[Required]
public string Occupation { get; set; }
```

I have an `OnPostAsync` Method that returns the page if the user submits invalid information

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  return Page();
}
```

If disable javascript (run server side validation) and submit a form with a blank Occupation field, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I instead return `RedirectToPage()`, everything is fine, but I don't get the error messages displayed on the client.

The official microsoft docs simply `return Page()`. Why I am I getting unhandled exceptions, and how can I preserve validation errors on the client while avoiding them?

Comment: tried a small app. works fine. unless you are using some property of some object (i.e. ViewBag) in cshtml which is set to null when returning Page()

Comment: Since you did not provide a detailed code, we are unable to determine what caused the problem. I suggest you provide us with reference to all the codes involved in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom validation and check for the field i.e if the field is blank or empty.

Documentation Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0
Refer this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_AH2MGti0A